# $ \frac{a^{2}}{a+2 b^{3}}+\frac{b^{2}}{b+2 c^{3}}+\frac{c^{2}}{c+2 a^{3}} \geq 1 $

Tags: inequality, proof-explanation, a.m.-g.m.-inequality, rearrangement-inequality

**Question**

Let.a, $b, c$ be positive real numbers with sum 3 . Prove that
$$
\frac{a^{2}}{a+2 b^{3}}+\frac{b^{2}}{b+2 c^{3}}+\frac{c^{2}}{c+2 a^{3}} \geq 1
$$

**my doubt** -

by using cauchy reverse technique i have estimate the given expression with difference of two another expression and i just want to prove that

$b \sqrt[3]{a^{2}}+c \sqrt[3]{b^{2}}+a \sqrt[3]{c^{2}} \leq 3$

now they write

According to AM-GM, we obtain
$$
3 \sum_{c y c} a \geq \sum_{c y c} a+2 \sum_{c y c} a b=\sum_{c y c}(a+a c+a c) \geq 3 \sum_{c y c} a \sqrt[3]{c^{2}}
$$

but how they proved that $
3 \sum_{c y c} a \geq \sum_{c y c} a+2 \sum_{c y c} a b$

this means that $a+b+c > ab+bc+ca$ how ???

i know this is little doubt but i want to clear it ....

thankyou

Comment: OP's questions seem to be from a book. He seems to be working on the AM-GM section currently (or at least, for the previous question).

Comment: @User88463 FYI These 2 recent questions are "very basic AM-GM", so maybe you should revisit the start of the book instead of reading deeper. They should have been almost immediate (in the sense that you know how to expand and force out the AM-GM if very desperate).

Comment: ohh,yeah i did not see it..thanks calvin

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Hint:** AM-GM

> $3 \sum a = (\sum a )^2 = (a^2+b^2+c^2) + 2\sum ab  = \left(\frac{1}{2} \sum ( a^2 + b^2 ) \right) + 2 \sum ab $
>  $ \geq \sum ab + 2 \sum ab  = 3 \sum ab $

Answer (score 0):

Another way.

We need to prove that $$a^3c^2+b^3a^2+c^3b^2\leq3$$ for non-negatives $a$, $b$ and $c$ such that $a^2+b^2+c^2=3$.

Indeed, let $\{a,b,c\}=\{x,y,z\}$, where $x\geq y\geq z$.

Thus, by Rearrangement, AM-GM and AM-GM we obtain:
$$a^3c^2+b^3a^2+c^3b^2=a\cdot a^2c^2+b\cdot b^2a^2+c\cdot c^2b^2\leq x\cdot x^2y^2+y\cdot x^2z^2+z\cdot y^2z^2=$$
$$=y(x^3y+x^2z^2+z^3y)=y\left(x^2\left(xy+\frac{z^2}{2}\right)+z^2\left(\frac{x^2}{2}+yz\right)\right)\leq$$
$$\leq y\left(x^2\left(\frac{x^2+y^2}{2}+\frac{z^2}{2}\right)+z^2\left(\frac{x^2}{2}+\frac{y^2+z^2}{2}\right)\right)=\frac{3}{2}y(3-y^2)\leq3.$$