# Prove that if $\sqrt{a}+\sqrt{b}+\sqrt{c}=3$ then $ \frac{a^{2}}{a+2 b^{2}}+\frac{b^{2}}{b+2 c^{2}}+\frac{c^{2}}{c+2 a^{2}} \geq 1 $

Tags: inequality, contest-math, a.m.-g.m.-inequality

**Question** -

Let $a, b, c$ be positive real numbers such that $\sqrt{a}+\sqrt{b}+\sqrt{c}=3$ . Prove that
$$
\frac{a^{2}}{a+2 b^{2}}+\frac{b^{2}}{b+2 c^{2}}+\frac{c^{2}}{c+2 a^{2}} \geq 1
$$

**My try**

$$
\frac{a^{2}}{a+2 b^{2}}=a-\frac{2 a b^{2}}{a+2 b^{2}} \geq a-\frac{2 a b^{2}}{3 \sqrt[3]{a b^{4}}}=a-\frac{2(a b)^{2 / 3}}{3}
$$
which implies that
$$
\sum_{c y c} \frac{a^{2}}{a+2 b^{2}} \geq \sum_{c y c} a-\frac{2}{3} \sum_{c y c}(a b)^{\frac{2}{3}}
$$
It suffices to prove that
$$
(a b)^{2 / 3}+( b c)^{2 / 3}+\left (c a)^{2 / 3} \leq 3\right.
$$

beacuse we can easily get that $\sum a \ge 3$

but i am not able to prove it..

note that we have to prove this using **only am-gm or weighted am-gm or power mean or any kind of means inequality** because author did not introduce any advance inequality yet...

any hints ???

thankyou

Comment: Does this answer your question? [$ \frac{a^{2}}{a+2 b^{3}}+\frac{b^{2}}{b+2 c^{3}}+\frac{c^{2}}{c+2 a^{3}} \geq 1 $](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3641757/fraca2a2-b3-fracb2b2-c3-fracc2c2-a3-geq-1)

Comment: obviously not...there a+b+c = 3 ..

Comment: But the inequality is different, and I believe with a substitution you can transform between the two. Sorry for the wrong suggestion

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is enough to show that $\sqrt a + \sqrt b + \sqrt c = 3 \implies (ab)^{2/3} + (bc)^{2/3} + (ca)^{2/3} \leqslant 3$.  For ease, let us replace $a, b, c$ with $x^6, y^6, z^6$, so we need to show for positives, $x^3+y^3+z^3=3 \implies (xy)^4+(yz)^4+(zx)^4\leqslant 3$.  This one is in fact a known old chestnut.

We note by AM-GM, $xy \leqslant \frac13(x^3+y^3+1) = \frac13(4-z^3)$, hence $(xy)^4 \leqslant \frac13(4x^3y^3-x^3y^3z^3)$.  Cyclically summing three such inequalities, we get
$$\sum (xy)^4 \leqslant \frac43\sum (xy)^3-(xyz)^3$$
Now with $X=x^3, Y = y^3, Z = z^3$, it is enough to show with $X+Y+Z=3$
$$4(XY+YZ+ZX) -3XYZ\leqslant 9$$ 
which is the well known Schur's inequality:
$$4(X+Y+Z)(XY+YZ+ZX) \leqslant (X+Y+Z)^3+9XYZ$$

Comment: In the third line , I think you meant $x^3+y^3+z^3$ instead of $x^3+y^3+x^3$?

Comment: @ Macavity How does the inequality in the second last line relate to the inequality in the last line?

Comment: Oh, never mind, ignore me. I understand it now. Nice solution!

Comment: how from this $xy \leqslant \frac13(x^3+y^3+1) = \frac13(4-z^3)$ you get $(xy)^4 \leqslant \frac13(4x^3y^3-x^3y^3z^3)$ ???

Comment: Not hard to work that out, its just multiplication by $(xy)^3$ on both sides.

Comment: ohh, yes ..i am trying to expanding out fourth power ....thankyou

Answer (score 2):

Another way.

By C-S and P-M we obtain:
$$\sum_{cyc}\frac{a^2}{a+2b^2}-1=\sum_{cyc}\frac{a^4}{a^3+2a^2b^2}-1\geq\frac{(a^2+b^2+c^2)^2}{\sum\limits_{cyc}(a^3+2a^2b^2)}-1=$$
$$=\frac{\sum\limits_{cyc}(a^4-a^3)}{\sum\limits_{cyc}(a^3+2a^2b^2)}=\frac{9(a^4+b^4+c^4)-(a^3+b^3+c^3)(\sqrt{a}+\sqrt{b}+\sqrt{c})^2}{9\sum\limits_{cyc}(a^3+2a^2b^2)}\geq0.$$
Because by P-M $$\sqrt[4]{\frac{a^4+b^4+c^4}{3}}\geq\sqrt[3]{\frac{a^3+b^3+c^3}{3}}$$ or $$\sqrt[4]{\left(\frac{a^4+b^4+c^4}{3}\right)^3}\geq\frac{a^3+b^3+c^3}{3}$$ or $$\sqrt[4]{3(a^4+b^4+c^4)^3}\geq a^3+b^3+c^3$$ and
$$\sqrt[4]{\frac{a^4+b^4+c^4}{3}}\geq\left(\frac{\sqrt{a}+\sqrt{b}+\sqrt{c}}{3}\right)^2$$ or
$$\sqrt[4]{2187(a^4+b^4+c^4)}\geq(\sqrt a+\sqrt b+\sqrt c)^2.$$
Id est, $$9(a^4+b^4+c^4)=\sqrt[4]{3(a^4+b^4+c^4)^3}\cdot\sqrt[4]{2187(a^4+b^4+c^4)}\geq$$
$$\geq(a^3+b^3+c^3)(\sqrt{a}+\sqrt{b}+\sqrt{c})^2.$$

Comment: finally god answered...i have some doubts in your proof 1) what is P-M , is it power mean ? 2) in last step how can we conclude that thing is greater then $0$ ?

Comment: @User88463 P-M it's Power Mean.

Comment: ok,but in last step how that is greater then 0 .. for that we have to prove that $a^4+b^4+c^4>a^3+b^3+c^3$....but by using PM we get that 4th root of $a^4+b^4+c^4$ is > then 3th root of $a^3+b^3+c^3$ can you pls tell how you get it??

Comment: @User88463 I added something. See now.

Answer (score 0):

**Elaborating on the above solution:**

We first wish to prove that the last inequality holds. Schur's inequality in its simplest form states that: For non-negative real numbers $x,y,z$, we have $x^3+y^3+z^3+3xyz \geq xy(x+y)+xz(x+z)+yz(y+z)$.

Now, expanding the R.H.S., we obtain: $(X+Y+Z)^3+9XYZ$

$=X^3+3X^2Y+3X^2Z+3XY^2+6XYZ+3XZ^2+Y^3+3Y^2Z+3YZ^2+Z^3+9XYZ$

$=X^3+Y^3+Z^3+3XYZ+12XYZ+3X^2Y+3X^2Z+3XY^2+3XZ^2+3Y^2Z+3YZ^2$

$\geq XY(X+Y) +XZ(X+Z) + YZ(Y+Z)+12XYZ+3X^2Y+3X^2Z+3XY^2+3XZ^2+3Y^2Z+3YZ^2$,

$=X^2Y+XY^2+X^2Z+XZ^2+Y^2Z+YZ^2+12XYZ+3X^2Y+3X^2Z+3XY^2+3XZ^2+3Y^2Z+3YZ^2$

$=4X^2Y+4XY^2+4X^2Z+4XZ^2+4Y^2Z+4YZ^2+12XYZ$

$=4(X^2Y+XYZ+XY^2+X^2Z+XYZ+XZ^2+Y^2Z+XYZ+YZ^2)$

$=4[XY(X+Y+Z)+XZ(X+Y+Z)+YZ(X+Y+Z)]$

$=4(X+Y+Z)(XY+YZ+ZX)$

Simply flipping the inequality sign gives us: $4(X+Y+Z)(XY+YZ+ZX) \leq (X+Y+Z)^3+9XYZ$, so we are done.

Finally, we observe that this inequality implies the second last inequality. With $X+Y+Z=3$, we have:

$4(X+Y+Z)(XY+YZ+ZX) \leq (X+Y+Z)^3+9XYZ$

$\Rightarrow 4(XY+YZ+ZX) \leq  \ (X+Y+Z)^2+3XYZ$

$\Rightarrow 4(XY+YZ+ZX) -3XYZ  \leq  \ (X+Y+Z)^2 = 3^2 =9$

(Q.E.D.)